# Some grew to remember me!

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Here's a quick easy one.

> Some grew to remember me,
>   On the ground, or up a tree,
>   I play well with R&B,
>   In large amounts, a sight to see.
>
> Throughout a valley, over hill,
>   A thing for which some men would kill,
>   I may be new, or if you're ill,
>   Round something yours that rhymes with chill.

What am I?

Comment: You are Brent Hackers. I don't know how many times we need to remind you.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Whenever I post, it's just a matter of time...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It could be

> The colour green

Some grew to remember me

> Primary Colours; red, green and blue

On the ground or up a tree

> Grass and Leaves

I play well with R&B

> RGB colours; Red, Green and Blue

In large amounts, a sight to see

> Large open fields

Throughout a valley, over a hill

> Hills and valleys tend to be green

A thing for which some men would kill for

> Money

I may be new, or if you're ill

> Green is used to describe something new. Sick people are described as going a shade of green

Round something yours that rhymes with chill

> 'Green around the gills'

Thanks @Silenus for filling in the blanks

Comment: "I may be new": "green" is a synonym for "new".

Comment: "if you're ill round something yours that rhymes with chill": "green around the gills" is a synonym for "ill".

Comment: Well done @Silenus  +1

Comment: @Silenus +1 again

Comment: I read "for which some men would kill" as envy, which I'm now surprised didn't make an appearance.  This was a good one though!

Comment: How does "Some grew to remember me" fit?