# One just for Gareth!

Tags: riddle

Please forgive me for this very silly riddle written just for a very silly puzzling regular.

> In two ways this riddle is bad,
>   And right now it's making me sad,
>   My mojo is gone,
>   Because of this one,
>   Riddles may have driven me mad!
>
> Even the site veterans might,
>   Not get the answer outright,
>   That is except for one,
>   He will soon be along,
>   And if you're not, he'll surely be right.
>
> Can you be the one to tell me,
>   Keep him from his victory,
>   EVERY time,
>   Repeats the same line,
>   So answer and then let me be!

Who am I?

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer :-) Unless you're waiting for Gareth to post an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are

> **(I AM) BRENT HACKERS** -> First letters of each line. And it's referring to [a comment made by  Gareth McCaughan :)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48953/some-grew-to-remember-me#comment149426_48953)

Comment: Ruddy hell.  I kind of expected as much but at least give me time to refresh the page.  +1

Comment: @BrentHackers Fortunately I read Gareth's comment(now deleted) the other day :)

Comment: Yeah.  There are plenty of them!  They're on a good 50%+ or my recent questions.  That's what I get for a couple of unimaginative enigmatic puzzles I guess. :P

Comment: Oh, didn't knew that fact :)